# Will generic earphones allow basic inline remote / mic capability on my iPhone 6?

Tags: iphone, audio, microphone, remote-control, compatibility

I'm interested in buying the [Sony XBAA1AP](https://www.sony.com.au/product/xba-a1ap) earphones, and am curious if earphones that aren't specifically designed for iPhones, but which have an inline remote control / mic, will provide basic remote control / mic features on iPhone devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, generic earphones/headphones/earpods will work fine with an iPhone.  I have several non-Apple headphones and earphones from various manufacturers and they've all worked, including the play/pause, ff/rw, volume buttons.

As long as you purchase from a reputable company and manufacturer, like you've indicated in your question, you'll be ok.